# single webpack build for multiple sets of env vars

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a prod build that needs to be built for 3 different 'environments' where the only thing that differs is an api root. Is there a way to only build once and then output 3 versions using the different api roots?

Comment: its not possible with webpack, but it is possible with a simple bash script...

Comment: @AdamWolski Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @AdamWolski @Kudla69 you actually can do this with webpack alone. Just create a base configuration and extend it like described [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#the-manual-way-configuring-webpack-for-multiple-environments): you will just have to change `output.path` for each extending config.

Comment: @Ivan I believe this requires three build each with different configs. OP wants a single build

Comment: @AdamWolski Then it's easier to make a bash script that will run webpack with different sets of values for variables, and pass root path via one of them.

Comment: @Ivan there are more than one ways to do this using bash for sure

Comment: I'm open to a bash solution if this is not possible with webpack